# Checking System Sound Level Through Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

So you know when you play audio (like opening a YouTube video) and click your system volume settings to see how loud it is? Like this?

[image]

I want to do the same with NodeJS, where I run a function and it continuously outputs the sound level, something like this:

```
let libraryThatGetsSound = require('libraryThatGetsSound');

while(true) {
     console.log(libraryThatGetsSound.soundLevel());
}
```

This application will run on the desktop itself, not in a browser.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these packages it might help

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/system-control
- https://github.com/LinusU/node-loudness
- https://github.com/jlonardi/node-audio-windows

Although I am not sure, but I think win-audio is either dead or it requires python

**EDIT - For Decibels maybe this will help
https://www.npmjs.com/package/decibel-meter

**UPDATE 2023**

You can have a look at the Web Audio API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API

Comment: This controls the system audio level, i want to know the current volume. Like to know if sound is being played or not

Comment: Check the usage, still not sure why it cries about win-audio
const vol = await loudness.getVolume() /// first 
audio.volume().then(volume => console.log(volume)) // get system volume // second

Also I can see lodness has muted(true) or muted(false) function to check is muted

Comment: can you give me some example code? This is the entire code I have: https://pastebin.com/raw/7upgWieR - ( have both win-audio and loudness installed on my Windows 10) It just prints my current system audio level, not if theres actual sound coming out

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood so maybe you want something more like this - see edited answer

Comment: Hi! I think this is something good if i was embedding it into my own webpage but how do I use this within NodeJS?

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution for this? I am also looking for the exact functionality you're showing in your post. The measure of system loudness as opposed to the set volume.